# Not able to read data from mongodb using camel route

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I am trying to read a mongodb collection and insert the data in different collection using apache camel. I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operation, writeConcern, writeConcernRef, dynamicity, outputType options cannot appear on a consumer endpoint`

Looks like there is some problem in operation attribute, please have a look.

**Camel Route**

```
private static final String SOURCE = "mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=findAll&dynamicity=true&outputType=DBCursor";
private static final String DESTINATION = "mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse2&operation=save";

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(SOURCE)
    .to(DESTINATION);
}
```

**Console Log**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-22 16:09:01.843 ERROR 4568 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operation, writeConcern, writeConcernRef, dynamicity, outputType options cannot appear on a consumer endpoint
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:126) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:41) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:887) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.era.conf.ApplicationConfiguration.main(ApplicationConfiguration.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operation, writeConcern, writeConcernRef, dynamicity, outputType options cannot appear on a consumer endpoint
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:73) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController$DaemonTask.run(CamelMainRunController.java:43) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController.start(CamelMainRunController.java:36) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:113) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operation, writeConcern, writeConcernRef, dynamicity, outputType options cannot appear on a consumer endpoint
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbEndpoint.validateOptions(MongoDbEndpoint.java:176) ~[camel-mongodb-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbEndpoint.createConsumer(MongoDbEndpoint.java:127) ~[camel-mongodb-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:69) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:98) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:158) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3490) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3420) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3197) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3053) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:127) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138) ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:68) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

**Update**

```
private static final String SOURCE = "mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=findAll"
```

Removed `dynamicity=true&outputType=DBCursor` from the *SOURCE*. Issue remains the same.

Comment: Remove this `dynamicity=true&outputType=DBCursor` and check

Comment: Same error log :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Spring Boot 2.0 with Camel 2.17. Official support for Spring Boot 2 is coming in the next Apache Camel 2.22 release. So switch back to Spring Boot 1.5.x for your application.

See also top of this page: http://camel.apache.org/camel-2210-release.html

**Updated**: Okay so its the option `dynamicity=true` you cannot have in your `SOURCE` so remove that.

Comment: I change to Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE but problem remains the same. No luck.

Comment: the components starter of Apache camel are released from 2.18.0.

Comment: Updated with answer

Comment: Removed `dynamicity=true&outputType=DBCursor` from the SOURCE, unfortunately issue remains the same. Also, changed `camel-spring-boot-starter` version to `2.18.0` & `spring-boot-starter-parent` to `1.5.10.RELEASE`